# NSToolbar on bottom of window

Tags: cocoa, nstoolbar

How do i put an NSToolbar on the bottom of a window. I need to modify a program that has a toolbar on the top of the window and that needs to go on the bottom now.

Answer (score 0):

In direct answer, NSToolbar won't cooperate without a lot of hackery.

Stepping back to a wider view: why not use the bottom margin of a window to put tools there? You won't get the user customization of NSToolbar but I'd argue putting a toolbar's worth of buttons on the bottom of the window should raise a lot of questions about your overall design approach. (Yes, I'm aware of things like iPhoto, etc. but it's still localized to a view, not the whole window and it doesn't "overflow" and isn't customizable.)

Comment: I need to put a toolbar like view at the bottom. The buttons there will be changed depending on what is selected in another view on the window.

Comment: Your best bet is probably to roll your own. Either swap out a view with one set of buttons for a view with a different set, or build your own single view that lays out buttons horizontally as they're added or removed.