# put NSToolBar on the bottom of window

Tags: cocoa, nstoolbar

I added a NSToolBar into my window. It is attached to the top of the window, but I need to put down it on the bottom. How can I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NSToolbar on bottom of window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977343/nstoolbar-on-bottom-of-window)

Comment: There is no answer on the question, only common words that it isn't easy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't afaik. NSToolbars are only meant to be attached to the top of a window. If you want NSToolbar like functionality at the bottom of the window, it basically means implementing something like it yourself. Besides even if you got NSToolbar to be on the bottom of a window, it'd break with general OS X UI expectations. If your talking about the minimal functionality of implementing custom buttons to trigger actions but along the bottom of a window then thats not hard at all to do yourself.

Comment: Strange :) Okay, I just replaced ToolBar by a set of buttons - I don't need any special functionality of ToolBar