# Toolbar customization works only on horizontal toolbars

Tags: objective-c, nstoolbar

ALL,

I'm trying to add the toolbar customization functionality to my program.

Everything works when the toolbar is horizontal on on top.

When the toolbar is vertical on and the left, calling https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nstoolbar/1516979-runcustomizationpalette?language=objc doesn't have any effect.

Is there a way to mitigate it?

Comment: How do I make a `NSToolbar` vertical?

Comment: @Willeke, you just set the position/size of the toolbar...

Comment: `NSToolbar` doesn't have a `position` or `size` property. Post a [mre] please.

Comment: @Willeke, it looks like only top horizontal NSToolbar can be customizable - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977343/nstoolbar-on-bottom-of-window.

Comment: So the vertical toolbar is not a `NSToolbar`?